# Can we retrieve the report of an older test?

Tags: karate

I ran a scenario A and its result was stored in surefire-reports(test 1). I ran the scenario A again and the new result was overwritten in the surefire-reports(test 2). Can i retrieve the report of test 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Are you aware of the JUnit HTML report ? You can open it in a browser tab twice and then refresh only one and compare.

https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-html-report